# Networkx: NetworkXException: nodelist contains duplicate for stochastic_block_model

Tags: python, nodes, networkx, graph-theory, nodelist

I'm new to networkx (version 2.4) and a bit puzzled by the error that I get for [stochastic_block_model](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.generators.community.stochastic_block_model.html) when I try to add a nodelist. I'm trying to have a different color attribute for each block in the network using this code:

```
import networkx as nx
N_p = 10
N_n = 10
N_0 = 30
sizes = [N_p, N_n, N_0]
probs = [[0.25, 0.05, 0.02],
         [0.05, 0.35, 0.07],
         [0.02, 0.07, 0.40]]
nodelist = ['blue' for i in range(N_p)]
nodelist.extend(['red' for i in range(N_n)])
nodelist.extend(['green' for i in range(N_0)])
G = nx.stochastic_block_model(sizes, probs,nodelist=nodelist, seed=0,directed=1)
```

But I get the following error message:

```
...
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/networkx/generators/community.py in stochastic_block_model(sizes, p, nodelist, seed, directed, selfloops, sparse)
    576             raise nx.NetworkXException("'nodelist' and 'sizes' do not match.")
    577         if len(nodelist) != len(set(nodelist)):
--> 578             raise nx.NetworkXException("nodelist contains duplicate.")
    579     else:
    580         nodelist = range(0, sum(sizes))

NetworkXException: nodelist contains duplicate.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is just that - the nodelist contains duplicates:

```
>>> nodelist
['blue'*10, 'red'*10, 'green'*30]
```

As in your documentation link:

> **Raises NetworkXError –**
>
> If probabilities are not in [0,1]. If the
>   probability matrix is not square (directed case). If the probability
>   matrix is not symmetric (undirected case). If the sizes list does not
>   match nodelist or the probability matrix. **If nodelist contains
>   duplicate.**

To fix this, either don't use a nodelist, or do something like the following:

```
nodelist = [f'blue_{i}' for i in range(N_p)]
nodelist.extend([f'red_{i}' for i in range(N_n)])
nodelist.extend([f'green_{i}' for i in range(N_0)])
```